# what is this concept called and from which version of java

Tags: java

Can you please let me know which version of java below flower bracket ({}) is introduced? what is concept name for this.

```
Object[] arg =  {abc.getAbctNumber()};
```

here abc is object of java class and getAbcNumber() is a java method. I understand that arg object will be assigned with the value of return value of getAbcNumber() method.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`{}` is used to specify an array literal. So in your case you're specifying an array of objects with one element.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a "flower bracket" in java.   What you are seeing here, is an array being populated by a method.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an array with this syntax similar to:

```
  int myarray[] = {1, 2, 3};
```

which will create an array of three ints. Your array will be created with an object.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a list initializer (not sure about the terminology, I don't do a lot of Java).  In this case `arg` is an array of type `Object` and it's being initialized with a single value, which is the result of `abc.getAbctNumber()`.

Consider an initializer with more than one value and it starts to become more clear:

```
Object[] arg = {
    abc.getAbctNumber(),
    abc.getSomeOtherNumber(),
    abc.getSomethingElse()
};
```

That would initialize the `arg` array with three elements, the results of three different methods.

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing called `Flower bracket`(at least I don't know about that). And in your `Object[] arg =  {abc.getAbctNumber()};` `{}` represent an `array` of one element and that element being an `Object` that is returned by method `getAbctNumber()`